# Incrementing strings of 10-bit length 'ID00000012' in PHP

Tags: php

While receiving an unknown 10-length string from the database which can be anything from "ID11111111" to "ID00000000". **Is there a formula that can increment their value by 1?** For example, if I received "ID00000012", can I call the function to increment it to "ID00000013".

I've attempted just doing `$newid = $latestid+1` but it doesn't work. I also attempted doing the following :

```
$newid = 'ID'+str_pad(substr($latestid, 2)+1, 8, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

But it keeps generating a result of '1' only.

Comment: This is probably something you should not let PHP do. Instead design your database to do this, and separate the number from the "ID" prefix there.

Comment: If the database creates these IDs, it should be capable of auto-incrementing them itself as well - so why do you need to do it in script?

Comment: `$id = "ID00000000"; $id++; echo $id; // ID00000001` – [docs](http://php.net/operators.increment).

Comment: @salathe I'm shocked that that works. One oddity - it seems to fail just the first time for me. Stays 0000000, but a subsequent increment works.

Comment: @ceejayoz maybe you're just doing it wrong?  https://3v4l.org/18mSB

Comment: I'm too surprised that works. You shouldn't be able to do math on strings like that. This is going to disturb my sleep. Damn you! :-)

Comment: @Andreas On behalf of PHP, I apologize.

Comment: @salathe Never mind. Tinker oddity!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split it and add one then rebuild it with [str_pad](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php).

```
$str ="ID00000012";

//Add one to numeric part
$n = substr($str,2)+1;
//Rebuild are with id and str_pad of $n
$str ="ID". Str_pad($n,8,0,STR_PAD_LEFT);
Echo $str;
```

https://3v4l.org/sd5HX